# Why are the html tags showing up in my string in PHP?

Tags: php, email, header, html-email

I'm using a mail function which is sending back a message that is contained within the variable $body. I want to send the message to myself with certain words in bold and a number of break tags.

Here is my code(HEREDOC SYNTAX):

```
$body = <<<CTS
<h1><b>Order for $name on datevariable</b></h1><br /><br />

<b><u>Administrative Details</u></b><br />
<b>Employee ID:</b> $id<br />
<b>Cost Center:</b> $cost_center<br />
<b>Approved By:</b> $approved_by<br />
<b>Delivery Bldg:</b> $delivery_bldg<br />
<b>Delivery Contact Email:</b> $delivery_contact<br />
<b>Ext:</b> $del_contact_ext<br />
CTS;
```

For some reason when I receive  the email, it looks like this:

```
<h1><b>Order for James Important on datevariable</b></h1><br /><br />
<b><u>Administrative Details</u></b><br />
<b>Employee ID:</b> 213123<br />
<b>Cost Center:</b> 132123<br />
<b>Approved By:</b> Chris Seckla<br />
<b>Delivery Bldg:</b> 6<br />
<b>Delivery Contact Email:</b> test@email.com<br />
<b>Ext:</b> 56<br />
```

It fills in the variable values but for some reason ignores the html tags. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Also, it is ignoring the break tags and only putting breaks when I leave a line of whitespace. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It worked great! Is the MIME and charset a big deal, because i noticed that only Phobis mentioned it and Marc chose not to mention it, but it worked regardless?

Comment: MIME-Version is usually only needed if you are dealing with attachments. The charset is only important if you have international characters or some other strange character set that most users' email clients won't handle by default. It's good practice to include them, but I chose not to for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If this is an email, you have to set the mime type to text/html instead of text/plain. Otherwise your email reader will interpret the message as plain text and ignore all the html tags.

For example, lets say you are calling the `mail` function like this:

```
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers )
```

In `$headers`, you'd need something along these lines (adjusted for your particular case, of course):

```
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: webmaster@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
```

If you want to send both plain text and html email (so non-html readers can see a clean version of the email without all those tags), I would suggest taking a look at [this](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php) tutorial for a more detailed explanation of multipart emails.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set an additional header when sending from php for the email to display using html format:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=whatever

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you send the header that states it is HTML...

example:

```
mail('email@domain.com', 'Subject',
'<html><body><b>Hello</b></body></html>',
"To: The Receiver <recipient@domain.com>\n" .
"From: The Sender <email@domain.com>\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

Comment: Whenever I include this line: "MIME-Version: 1.0\n", Apple Mail shows the HTML tags inside the body, I have to remove it to have Mail show HTML, why is this anyone?

Comment: You need to add the header: Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to send mail with PHP I would recommend you with PEAR Mail_Mime package instead of plain mail function